# Rxjs with HTTP - fetch first page, then the rest of pages

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an HTTP REST API that returns a list of rules. I want to get the first page of rules, then make parallel HTTP requests for the rest of the pages. I need the first page to know how many pages are in total.

**My goal: Return an observable with the list of data from all pages as soon as ALL of the HTTP requests have ended (and not just update a variable on the fly as it works now).**

Current code:

```
getRules(category) {
    this.http.get(`rules?page=0&size=8000&category=${category}`)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        let rulesData = [];
        this.loading = true;
        if (data.last === false) {
            rulesData = rulesData.concat(data.content);
          const pages = [];
          if (data.totalPages > 20) {
            data.totalPages = 20;
          }
          for (let i = 1; i <= data.totalPages - 1; i++) {
            pages.push(i);
          }
          return Observable.forkJoin(
            pages.map(
              i => this.http.get(`rules?page=${i}&size=8000&category=${category}`)
            )
          ).subscribe((event: any) => {
            this.totalCount = event[0].totalElements;
            event.forEach((entry) => {
              rulesData = rulesData.concat(entry.content);
            });
            this.rulesData = rulesData;
            this.loading = false;
          });
        } else {
          this.appRulesData = data.content;
          this.loading = false;
        }
      }, (err) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.error = err;
      });
  }
```

Any idea of how I can use Rxjs to return an observable with the data from all pages?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get just one observable, it's better to transform the first one using [pipe](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/concepts/rxjs-primer#pipe) and [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap), instead of subscribing to it. I've also used [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) and [finalize](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/finalize) to track the progress.

```js
import { forkJoin, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, tap, switchMap, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

function loadPagesInfo() {
  return of({
    pageCount: 3
  }).pipe(
    delay(1000)
  );
}

function loadPage(pageIndex) {
  return of({
    pageIndex: 1
  }).pipe(
    delay(1000)
  );
}

function loadPages() {
  return loadPagesInfo().pipe(
    tap(()=> {
      console.log("loading start");
    }),
    switchMap(pagesInfo => {
      return forkJoin(
        new Array(pagesInfo.pageCount)
          .fill(0)
          .map((_, pageIndex) => loadPage(pageIndex))
      )
    }),
    finalize(() => {
      console.log("loading end");
    })
  );
}

loadPages().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(`result: ${result}`);
});
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-menpps)